# postfix: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql

Tags: 16.04, mysql, email, postfix

I just was installing new mail server on Ubuntu 16.04, starting my installing and configuring postfix and mysql,:

```
apt install postfix postfix-mysql mysql-server mysql-client
```

After configuring postfix (3.1) and create db base for the mail, i tried to test if postfix can reach the db and retrieve all domains / users:

```
postmap -q mydomain.com mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
```

I got the error:

```
postmap: fatal: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
```

Seems my server doesn't support mysql for some reason!

```
# postconf -m
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
inline
internal
memcache
nis
pipemap
proxy
randmap
regexp
socketmap
static
tcp
texthash
unionmap
unix

/etc/postfix# cat dynamicmaps.cf 
# dict-type so-name (pathname)  dict-function   mkmap-function
cdb postfix-cdb.so.1.0.1    dict_cdb_open   mkmap_cdb_open
ldap    postfix-ldap.so.1.0.1   dict_ldap_open
mysql   postfix-mysql.so.1.0.1  dict_mysql_open
pcre    postfix-pcre.so.1.0.1   dict_pcre_open
pgsql   postfix-pgsql.so.1.0.1  dict_pgsql_open
sqlite  postfix-sqlite.so.1.0.1 dict_sqlite_open
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 6):

After installing `postfix-mysql` try restarting postfix:

```
postfix reload
```

Answer (score 4):

After many hours spending time on this issue, I found and resolved it:

change `mysql` line in file `/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf` to:

```
mysql   /usr/lib/postfix/postfix-mysql.so.1.0.1 dict_mysql_open
```

and then reload postfix `postfix reload`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your case, I realized that forgot to install postfix-mysql. After do,

```
apt install postfix-mysql
```

the line,

```
mysql   /usr/lib/postfix/postfix-mysql.so.1.0.1 dict_mysql_open
```

was automatically added on /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf, but AFAIK not in your case. Is strange.